# What will be the output for this logic?

Tags: c

I have the below code. But, I think 4 is the answer. Am I right?

```
int a, i;

if (execute)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    if(pcnt[i]) count ++;
  }
  a = (count > 0)
}
else
{
  a= 0;
}
```

Will a be a=1 or a=4 for the IF case?

Comment: Run the code and find out...

Comment: How can `a` be four after this?

Comment: where is `pcnt[]` defined?

Comment: 4 sure not 4. 1 and only case `a` is 1 is when `execute` is true... Otherwise should be 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `a` will be `1` or `0`

`1`: If `execute != 0` and `count >0`

`0`: otherwise

**Note:**

`count >0` if and only if `pcnt[0]!=0` or `pcnt[1]!=0` or `pcnt[2]!=0` or `pcnt[3]!=0` or `pcnt[4]!=0`

Comment: I think you mean "if `execute != 0`".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's right I miseed it

Answer (score 0):

First, this won't compile because of a missing semi-colon. It also might have difficulty if the variables are not declared properly, but for the sake of answering, I will assume that they have been.

Now, look at what `a` is assigned to. I see `a = (count > 0)` and `a = 0`. Well `(count > 0)` will only ever be a 0 or a 1 (in C boolean expressions will resolve to 1 for true and 0 for false). So basically, you have `a = 0 or 1` and `a = 0`. This simplifies to `a` being either 0 or 1.